# How to make periodic AJAX calls to cross-domain server

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to figure out how to make periodic AJAX calls to a [cross-domain hostname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). For example, how can I serve content from `example.com` and make an AJAX call to `example.org` every 30 seconds.

The canonical solution to this question is a [JSONP call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) in a `<script>` tag.  However, the `<script>` tag is just loaded once. Therefore, it can not generate periodic calls to another server - just a single call when the page loads.

**Is there a way to make a *periodic* AJAX call to a cross-domain server?**

Comment: You'll want to look into `setInterval()` to setup your periodic calls. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: How can `setInterval()` be used in the context of a `script` tag?

Comment: your script tag includes the code that calls setInterval, which executes a function every interval that makes the same AJAX request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code. We're using `setInterval` to call our `ping()` function every 3 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ping() {
    $.ajax({
      ...
    });
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    ping();
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Can the AJAX code inside the `script` tag be loaded from an external file?

Comment: Sure; if you mean, including a `src` attribute instead of the code locally :)